# Convert Q1-Q4 period strings to datetime using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is a sample with date format:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter':['Q1_01','Q2_01', 'Q3_01', 'Q4_01', 'Q1_02','Q2_02']
                     , 'Sale' :[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]})

print(data)

#   Quarter  Sale
#0  Q1_01    10
#1  Q2_01    20
#2  Q3_01    30
#3  Q4_01    40
#4  Q1_02    50
#5  Q2_02    60

print(data.dtypes)
# Quarter    object
# Sale        int64
```

Would like to convert Quarter column into Pandas datetime format like
'**Jan-2001**' or '**01-2001**' that can be used in ***fbProphet*** for time series analysis.

Tried using strptime but got an error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series`

```
from datetime import datetime

data['Quarter'] = datetime.strptime(data['Quarter'], 'Q%q_%y')
```

What is the cause of the error ? Any better solution?

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed.  Tried to comment something but not sure why the markdown wont change to coding formating

Comment: I have edited my answer. Any further follow ups should go into a new question. This was a tough one as it is.

Comment: TQVM. Yup... quarterly date is not so commonly used :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing the format `to_datetime` needs to pass period indices is helpful (it is along the lines of `YYYY-QX`), so we start with `replace`, then `to_datetime` and finally `strftime`:

```
u = df.Quarter.str.replace(r'(Q\d)_(\d+)', r'20\2-\1')
pd.to_datetime(u).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

0    Jan-2001
1    Apr-2001
2    Jul-2001
3    Oct-2001
4    Jan-2002
5    Apr-2002
Name: Quarter, dtype: object
```

The month represents the start of its respective quarter.

---

If the dates can range across the 90s and the 2000s, then let's try something different:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter':['Q1_98','Q2_99', 'Q3_01', 'Q4_01', 'Q1_02','Q2_02']}) 

dt = pd.to_datetime(df.Quarter.str.replace(r'(Q\d)_(\d+)', r'\2-\1'))
(dt.where(dt <= pd.to_datetime('today'), dt - pd.DateOffset(years=100))
   .dt.strftime('%b-%Y'))

0    Jan-1998
1    Apr-1999
2    Jul-2001
3    Oct-2001
4    Jan-2002
5    Apr-2002
Name: Quarter, dtype: object
```

`pd.to_datetime` auto-parses "98" as "2098", so we do a little fix to subtract 100 years from dates later than "today's date".

This hack will stop working in a few decades. Ye pandas gods, have mercy on my soul :-)

---

Another option is parsing to `PeriodIndex`:

```
(pd.PeriodIndex(df.Quarter.str.replace(r'(Q\d)_(\d+)', r'20\2-\1'), freq='Q')
   .strftime('%b-%Y'))
# Index(['Mar-2001', 'Jun-2001', 'Sep-2001', 
#        'Dec-2001', 'Mar-2002', 'Jun-2002'], dtype='object')
```

Here, the months printed out are at the ends of their respective quarters. You decide what to use.

Comment: Thanks alot. sorry. still a newbie in Stack